# jQuery append div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

So I'm making this thing in jQuery where if the user clicks a button a div appears and asks the user to enter some notes(basically a sticky note feature).

The HTML and CSS are done correctly, the only problem is that the jQuery won't work:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#top-tabs ul li").hover(function() {
        $(this).find("ul>li").stop().fadeToggle(400);
    });

    $("#submitpnote").on("click", function() {
        $("body").append("<div id='pnoteprompt'><input id ='input-pnote'type='text' placeholder='your note title'></input><input id ='input-pnote-p'type='text' placeholder='your note'></input><button id=confirmpnote>confirm note</button></div>");
        $("#pnote-prompt").fadeTo(100, 1);

    });

    $("#confirmpnote").on("click", function() {
        var $pnotetitle = document.getElementById("input-pnote").value;
        var $pnotep = document.getElementById("input-pnote-p").value;
        $("#pnotes-list").append("<div class='pnote-title'><li>" + $pnotetitle + "<br>" + $pnotep + "</li></div>");
        $("#pnoteprompt").remove();
    });

});
```

The js jQuery file is linked properly. It's just that in the submitpnote function(the second on), the div doesn't append. I click the button and nothing appears on my screen. I've tried putting some prompt() debuggers and the method is running but the div doesn't seem to be appending.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `" "` with `' '`?

`$("body").append('<div id="pnoteprompt"><input id="input-pnote" type="text" placeholder="your note title"></input><input id="input-pnote-p" type="text" placeholder="your note"></input><button id="confirmpnote">confirm note</button></div>');`

Html attributes have to have double quotes, not single ones.

Comment: In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it confirmpnote is dynamically created content, so you can't do $(#confirmnote) since that won't exist at the point that code is executed.

For dynamically created content use:

```
(document).on('click', 'selector', function(){
 //to stuff
});
```

selector would be #confirmpnote for example

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are adding the container that has `submitpnote` button dynamically so you would have to add the even handler using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitpnote', function(e){
  $(e.delegateTarget).append("<div id='pnoteprompt'><input id ='input-pnote'type='text' placeholder='your note title'></input><input id ='input-pnote-p'type='text' placeholder='your note'></input><button id=confirmpnote>confirm note</button></div>");
  $("#pnote-prompt").fadeTo(100, 1);
});
```